# Angular - ViewContainerRef.injector vs Injector

Tags: javascript, angular

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent{
    constructor(injector:Injector, vc:ViewContainerRef){
        console.log(injector===vc.injector)
    }
}
```

In a component I can inject `Injector` as well as `ViewContainerRef`. `ViewContainerRef`'s instance also has `injector` property. Naturally I would think it is the same instance as the `Injector`'s. However, running the above code outputs `false` in the console.

This makes me wonder what `ViewContainerRef`'s injector is and what it is for?

Comment: Good question. Its always false for me too. Yet if you compare the individual properties by printing out the instance, they are all identical.

Comment: I wonder what would a ViewContainerRef instance provided via DI in a component constructor do? Like, clearly its possible bc we both just did it. But surely it wouldn't let you overwrite the components view, would it?  They are usually used on embedded elements and referenced w/ directives or viewchild queries. I'm not sure what the viewcontainerref of a component actually means when its injected through DI like this. Bc each component also has a higher level 'ViewRef'

Comment: when you inject it like that and try to run any of the methods you'd normally use on an embedded view container, they all return null or undefined.

Comment: I think you can use it to create component dynamically next to this component. https://netbasal.com/angular-2-understanding-viewcontainerref-acc183f3b682

Comment: You can do that if you have a VCR of an element embedded inside the component, not the VCRef of the component itself.

Comment: Because when you create components dynamically like that, they are placed adjacent to the viewcontainerref element that they attach to. Not within it. So if you were doing that to an entire component, that would mean it would be creating sometihng outside of and adjacent to itself. Which i guess is technically possible but it breaks the one way data flow paradigm of Angular 2 / 4.

Comment: It is possible because the link in my previous comment shows that. Not sure how that breaks one way data flow though.

Comment: indeed it is...and i just tested it. wonder when / if this would be preferred to controlling the same thing in the parent componetn

Comment: Can the dynamically created component get hold of the original component's instance through DI?

Comment: no, that creates a circular dependency error.

Comment: BUT - you can manually add the parent instance from within the parent after creating it.   Once you create it with the componentFactoryResolver, you can go -> yourComponentRef.instance['parent'] = this;

And then it looks like all the data is accessible in both places.

Comment: You use same class for dynamic component? What about different class?

Comment: I've been using a different class. I have a modal factory that can create any number of dialogs / modals / popups / etc. So it can spawn like 3 or 4 different dynamic components, but they are all different classes. I just always though it had to be done inside the component, but with this method you can spawn them as a sibling to the component. So you don't even really need the redundant empty anchor elements i have in most components like this

Comment: It's not circular dependency error. It's "no provider" for the parent component. Check my test: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g5tavv So the dynamic component doesn't inherit from VCR's injector.

Comment: I didn't just make up the error.  Lol.  I tried it as we were talking and that's the error I got. Our implementations are different

Comment: It's a different error in your case because they are all contained within the same file, it doesn't need to import anything.